# Load and set Render Texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render-to-texture

I have got CamFeed.rendertexture and CamFeed.mat files. Im loading them using my script and setting it up to the camera as target texture and material to another quad respectively but it just shows a black screen.

```
Material newMat = Resources.Load("CamFeed", typeof(Material)) as Material;
RenderTexture rendertexture = Resources.Load("CamFeed", typeof(Material)) as RenderTexture;

FirstPersonCamera.targetTexture = rendertexture;
quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = newMat;
```

How can I be able to sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, why are you converting a `typeof(Material)` into `RenderTexture`? You should have one of each in your `Resources` folder, named distinctively, so that you instantiate them the following way:

```
Material newMat = Resources.Load<Material>("CamFeedMaterial");
RenderTexture rendertexture = Resources.Load<RenderTexture>("CamFeedTexture");
```

Also make sure that your material uses a shader such as `Unlit\Texture`, since you are going to need to attach the `RenderTexture` to it, either in the Editor or from code:

```
newMat.mainTexture = rendertexture;
```

Finally, your last bit of code stays the same:

```
FirstPersonCamera.targetTexture = rendertexture;
quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = newMat;
```

Comment: is it a best practice to call it in the start method or awake?

Comment: @user1241241 I don't believe there's much difference performance-wise for such a simple code, but I personally would place the Resources.Load<> calls in the Awake() and the rest in the Start()